# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/skynetdb] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc]

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jdbc

While deploying a project with jndi resource facing this error.

**javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/skynetdb] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc]**

Here "jdbc/skynetdb" is the name of the jndi resource defined in context.xml file as:

```
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        global="jdbc/skynetdb" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
        name="jdbc/skynetdb" password="" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/skynetdb" username="root" />
```

And dataSource bean in spring.xml file is declared as:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/skynetdb" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem solved:
I just modified the dataSource bean in spring.xml file as shown:**

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/skynetdb" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set this property 'resourceRef' for class JndiObjectFactoryBean

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/skynetdb" />
    <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Hope this will work

Thanks
Karthick